# ¿Cuales son las razones por la que el sistema operativo de Android silencia las notificaciones?

Tags: android, android-notifications

Tengo una app en la que implemento los canales de notificaciones pero hay ciertos casos que al recibir la notificación esta no suena a pesar de que no se han movido las configuraciones del dispositivo.
 Mi sospecha es que el SO las silencia automáticamente bajo ciertos casos relacionados al estado del dispositivo ¿me pueden mencionar cuales son todos estos casos y si hay documentación acerca de ellos?

Comment: Son varias las razones : https://support.google.com/android/answer/9069335?hl=en recuerda que las preguntas en el sitio deben basarse en [ask] y no deben estar basadas en "opiniones", realiza el [tour] para conocer su funcionamiento.

Comment: Depende también de la configuración que definas en código, puedes definir que no genere ningún sonido.

Comment: Desde la configuración también puedes determinar silenciar las notificaciones de determinada aplicación.